# How display notification in outlook client?

Tags: visual-studio, outlook-addin

I have create a add-in project in visual studio, I have so the project "display properties". It works. But if I add this line

```
app.showNotification("loadProps", "My function");
```

in the function `loadProps()`, my taskpane is now empty.

What i must do to use app.showNotification?

Comment: Here you go: [NotificationMessages](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/NotificationMessages?product=outlook)

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't see your point ? I don't understand why my task pane is blank when I just add a notification.

Comment: Ok, I understand why it didn't work, it's because I don't must use app, just showNotification. But now I have another question. I edit my post

Comment: NotificationMessages is the object which belongs to particular item in mailbox. When set, they will appear in the item view. [The example may look like this.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/images/block-on-send-body.png)